# Basecamp 2 Api: Possible to change attachments tags?

Tags: api, basecamp

Basecamp 2 api v.1

This changes the attachment's filename and returns 200:

```
resource['projects/11738xxx/attachments/2564xxxx.json'].put({"name"=> "HALLO.jpg"}.to_json)
=> <RestClient::Response 200 "{\"id\":2564....">
```

This returns 200 but doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
resource['projects/11738xxx/attachments/2564xxxx.json'].put( {"tags"=> ["tag1"]}.to_json )
=> <RestClient::Response 200 "{\"id\":2564....">
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, updating tags happens through the tags api: https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/tags.md